# Polar chart with R plotly package missing points

Tags: r, plotly

I have a dataset with values from 4 different groups. I could plot all the values in `plotly` as scatterplot with normal cartesian coordinate. But when I plotted the same for polar coordinate, only 1 value of each group was displayed.

To replicate, my toy data set is

```
bing <- structure(list(name = c("A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "D", 
"D", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "D", "B", "C", "B"), 
    prob = c(10162L, 6L, 1838L, 5296L, 419L, 9340L, 7981L, 7524L, 
    9657L, 13349L, 9159L, 20612L, 12619L, 6404L, 7364L, 15878L, 
    6903L, 9185L, 1478L, 2310L)), .Names = c("name", "prob"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I plotted the cartesian scatter plot with `plot_ly(bing, type="scatter",x=prob, y=name, mode="markers")` and got the following which shows the points.

[image]

I plotted it using polar coordinate with `plot_ly(bing, type="scatter",r=prob, t=name, mode="markers")` and got the following which has only four points.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if `plot_ly()` accepts strings / factors as its `r` parameter but the following worked for me. I essentially mapped the strings to numbers as shown below.

```
plot_ly(bing, type = "scatter", 
    r = as.numeric(as.factor(name)), 
    t = prob, mode = "markers", 
    color = name)
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks for this. What I was looking for is `r=prob` and `t=as.numeric(as.factor(name))*90` (with the 90 to make everything stay along the x and y axes). As you said, looks like I need to convert everything to degrees for `t`.